# Blocking webpage in Iptable

Tags: linux, bash, networking, ip

i am looking at writing a script to edit an Iptable. What i want to do is block facebook but allow access to it between one and two o'clock for break purposes. I have blocked facebook by simply dropping the packets but i am unsure on how to set time constraints, any ideas ??

Comment: What do you mean by "block"? Inbound or outbound traffic? Are you talking about a server or your desktop PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT ... -m time --timestart 13:00 --timestop 14:00 -j ACCEPT
```